# Django what to do when 2 people simultaneously purchase

Tags: django

I was wondering if anyone know what to do when I have a physical product and 2 people simultaneously purchase at the same time with the stock of 1? How do I make sure that even if they have the product in their cart they can't keep going forward with the payment process if the other person payed before them. Also if they haven't started the payment process and they just logged back into the website and they checked their cart(if they had the product in their cart already) I want it where they inform the users why they deleted the product from their cart. Something like this Ex:"Due to the product being out of stock we placed it in your wishlist...". Don't have a wishlist so just saying we deleted it from your cart. If anyone can help me with this I would be grateful because everytime I look this up I can't find any info about it. Only about other stuff and I'm thinking Im the only one going through this. Can someone explain what to do like really how to do it.

Comment: You have to check when user trying to do payment   `if Products.objects.filter(id=id).exists():` or you can use `get_object_or_404` or any other thing.

Answer (score 0):

It might happen in race condition, you can use get_or_create to prevent from race condition.

Comment: sorry for the late response but how would I implement this to my code?